# LLDB API : How to call a method of object stored in SBValue

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

I have a value of type sc_time, that has method

```
inline double sc_time::to_double() const
```

Can I call this method from debugger to get returned value? Is it possible at all?

```
// lldb::SBValue cur_time
cout << "IsInScope: " << cur_time.IsInScope() << endl;
cout << "Name: " << cur_time.GetName() << endl;
cout << "Type Name: " << cur_time.GetType().GetName() << endl;
```

returns

```
IsInScope: 1
Name: m_curr_time
Type Name: sc_core::sc_time
```

I've tried

```
cur_time.CreateValueFromExpression("retval", "to_double()")
cur_time.CreateValueFromExpression("retval", "m_curr_time.to_double()")
cur_time.CreateValueFromExpression("retval", "this->to_double()")
```

None worked

Comment: I guess my problem is that method is inlined. And thus not available to debugger.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
class sc_time
{
public:
    double to_double() const { return 123.456; // mock }
};
```

Load config file in `~/.lldbinit`:

```sh
command script import ~/.lldbcfg/print_sc_time.py
```

The config file for printing sc_time class instance:
`$HOME/.lldbcfg/print_sc_time.py`:

```py
def print_sc_time(valobj, internal_dict):
    res = str(valobj.EvaluateExpression("to_double()").GetValue())
    return res

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -P sc_time -F {:s}.print_sc_time'.format(__name__))
```